# Can this be done with jquery?

Tags: jquery, flash, animation, fade

Please take a look at this site [trmc.org](http://www.trmc.org/index.cfm)

Look at the flash header, can something like that be done with jquery? If so what jquery plug in would work the best? I've searched for image slide shows, but nothing with that effect can be found. Possibly the best method I found is spritely.

I look forward to your answers.

Comment: Fading/unfading images can be a little shaky without Flash, particularly on old versions of IE and with images that have alpha channels ("transparent PNG").  Also, I'm not sure how you'd do the blur effect.

Comment: @Pointy You create a blurred version of the image first, and fade to it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on in that header so I'm not sure exactly the effect you're looking for. Pretty sure the images coming into focus and the rings moving would be difficult to do in JavaScript.

However, if you're talking about a big banner that has rotating images, I've implemented this a few times using [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/). I've even found that [jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) is easier to use and will work in most cases when you don't need a bunch of customization.

Comment: Sorry, basically the pictures sliding in and the text transforming. The ring effect doesn't need to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think that could be done with jquery but I dunno what the performance of this would be like.

https://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/live-tutorials/postcard/index.html there is an example of a jquery postcard with repeating animations.

Answer (score 0):

The movement of image and texts are easy to implement.

The blur effect is not possible with JS (except in IE) but you can make something similar with .fadeIn() fadeOut() to change the transparency.

The circles "wave" is also possible with images and playing with theirs size and transparency.